# Equivalent of ApplicationRegistry.register in SBA 2.01?

Tags: spring-boot-admin

With SBA 1.5.4, I've been using `ApplicationRegistry.register` for custom registration of instances.

Trying to use `InstanceRegistry.register` for the same purpose with SBA 2.0.1 doesn't work as expected: my registered instances don't appear anywhere.

How is it possible to programatically register an instance?

Answer (score 0):

`InstanceRegistry.register` is the correct method but you need to subscribe to the returned `Mono` otherwise it has no effect.